# Can I instruct the Forest nodes to be at a certain level?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

The MWE below is a machine-generated organizational chart. It works almost fine, except for those employees, who report to more than one supervisor. I had to add regular TikZ nodes and draw the arrows. The problem with them is when multiple 2nd bosses overlap above a bunch of vertically aligned employees. Thus the acrobatics with `xshift` which I cannot find a way to automate yet (for those two who have the pink supervisors). Automating the green supervisor's placement is kind of Okay, but still not 100% reliable: it can be overlapped by the pink ones.

I could not make the pink nodes children of those white nodes where the connecting arrows originated, as I did not know of a way to force them to float up into the 2nd level, thus I added them after the Forest was generated as the regular TikZ nodes. Thus they would not benefit from automatic placement and compaction that Forest offered.

If there was a way to convert those TikZ nodes into the Forest nodes, and tell them to reside in the 1st two levels, preferrably staggering vertically, that would be an ideal solution. If that is not possible, then at least they should try to occupy all space in either 1st or 2nd level.

Is that possible?

Edit: Well, on a 2nd thought, the pink 2nd bosses should float at the 2nd level, while I can keep any green 2nd boss at the 1st level. That would probably be the most consistent way to specify the requirements.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=6ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\scriptsize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-4ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where n children=0{
        child anchor=west,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for parent={
            parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge%, draw=blue         
        } %,draw=red
    }{}, base=b
}
[\textbf{DDDDDDDDDDDD}\\
SSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTT\\MMMMMMMMMMM 
,name=10005073
    [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn}\\
dddddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10005654
        [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnnnn}\\
dddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10005155
[,phantom, minimum height=1ex]
    [\textbf{10003570}\\
ddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10003570]
    [\textbf{10003862}\\
dddddddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10003862]
    [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnnn}\\
ddddddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10005556]
]
    [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnn}\\
dddddddddddddd\\ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10003454[,phantom]]
    [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnn}\\
ddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10003770[,phantom]]
    [\textbf{nnnnnnnnnnn}\\
ddddddddddddddddd\\oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
,name=10004035[,phantom]]
]]
 %
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, align=center, draw=black!20, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex}}
\node[anchor=south,draw=black,fill=red!25](80000000) at ([xshift=-8em]10003570 |- 0,-4.5ex) {
\textbf{Boss Of 10003570}\\
VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM 
}[];
\draw[->,dashed,thick,black] (10003570) to (80000000);
\node[anchor=south,draw=black,fill=red!25](80000001) at ([xshift=8em]10003862 |- 0,-4.5ex) {
\textbf{Boss Of 10003862}\\
VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM 
}[];
\draw[->,dashed,thick,black] (10003862) to (80000001);
 %
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you write `[some node, tier=thisone...]` for relevant nodes, those nodes will all be placed on the same level. This is subject to some limitations, of course. (E.g. if you specify the same tier for the parent of a node and that node, `forest` cannot miraculously put them on the same level and make one a child of the other.) But generally, it should do what you want, I think. (But I'm not entirely sure I've understood what you need here.)

Comment: You see two pink nodes side by side, because I manually added `xshift` after seeing how they would overlap otherwise. They would overlap because they are Tikz nodes, and did not benefit from automatic placement by Forest. I made them regular Tikz nodes as I did not know, how to force them to the 2nd level of the Forest. Does that explain things at all, or am I still confusing you? :(

Comment: Why do you particularly want the pink ones to be children of nodes in level 3? That is, why is it so important that they have that relationship as far as `forest` is concerned? I suspect what you want can't be done but I keep coming back to this because I don't understand why you want to do it at all, and that makes me suspect I've misunderstood.

Comment: @cfr 1) The org charts can be very large and complex and I need those nodes auto-placed without overlapping, no matter whose children they are. 2) They have to be in the level 1. Currently the workaround is to use the regular TikZ nodes positioned "right above" and staggering them up and down. That still does not work in 100% cases. If Forest did the placement, it would have worked for any chart.

Comment: But why do they have to officially be children of those nodes? If they could simply be added as regular nodes at level 1, you might be able to use `forest`'s dynamic tree stuff to add them in. (That is, you could have the code for the nodes later in the tree but still have them placed in level 1.) But they would not then be children of later nodes and this is not something which I think `forest` can do. (What you want is not really a *tree* and `forest` does trees.) Have you looked at the graph drawing libraries? That may be closer to what you want.

Comment: @cfr Are you proposing making them children of the root node with no edges, then drawing the edges from their subordinates further down in the tree? This is a great idea which did not occur to me! That should just work. Although I do see a potential problem: without being children of the subordinate nodes, the 2nd bosses will not end up anywhere near above their subordinates.

Comment: Well... That is roughly what my initial tree did except that I didn't draw the connections because they were so faint in your image that I didn't see them.

Answer (score 2):

I am still not sure I understand the question. However, I was independently curious about this so here goes.

This solution allows you to specify the pink bosses as the children of whichever nodes you like. All you need do is specify `pink boss` for the relevant nodes. However, the parent of such a node should be one of those you wish typeset as if it had no children as setting the pink boss as its child will enforce that style. The style of the terminal nodes is repeated in the code for the `pink boss` style but pushed back to the parent.

You also need to tell `forest` which is the real, original level 1 node. To get the alignment with the level 0 root, you need to pass

```
before packing={calign with current},
```

This is actually getting executed ***after*** the pink bosses are moved, which is itself being delayed somewhat by the code you must pass to get the pink bosses moved to level 1:

```
  before typesetting nodes={
    repeat=\thepinkbosses{TeX={\stepcounter{countbosses}},insert before=pink boss \thecountbosses},
  }
```

This invokes `forest`'s support for dynamic trees (section 3.3.8 in the current manual), as well as its ability to execute TeX code and run loops.

At least one pink boss should be included. If this might not be the case, you would need to run parts of this code conditionally, I expect.

The connections between the pink bosses and the nodes which were originally their parents are drawn automatically after the tree has been drawn.

The code requires two counters which it uses to keep track of the number of pink bosses and of the relationship between the pink bosses and their parents. If a pink boss has more than one parent, you will need to add the connections to additional parents yourself. If you typeset more than one tree in the same document, you will need to reset the counters between trees. The code leaves your `name` settings untouched. Rather than changing these, it uses aliases `pink boss n` and `pink n` for parent-child pairing `n`.

I have never done several things in this code before. It is almost certainly fragile, definitely wonky and probably incorrect. Your footspeed may vary.

***Caveat emptor...***

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{pinkbosses}
\setcounter{pinkbosses}{0}
\newcounter{countbosses}
\setcounter{countbosses}{0}
\tikzset{
  /forest,
    pink boss/.style={
      for parent={child anchor=north},
      edge path={},
      fill=red!25,
      TeX={\stepcounter{pinkbosses}},
      alias=pink boss \thepinkbosses,
      for parent={
        child anchor=west,
        calign=child edge,
        alias=pink \thepinkbosses,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
    },
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      draw=black,
      align=center,
      l sep=6ex,
      node options={font=\scriptsize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
      where n children=0{}{
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-4ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
      where level=2{
        for descendants={
          where n children=0{
              child anchor=west,
              calign=child edge,
              edge path={
                  \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                  ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
              },
              for parent={
                parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge,
              },
            }{},
        },
      }{},
      base=b
  }
  [\textbf{DDDDDDDDDDDD}\\SSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTT\\MMMMMMMMMMM, name=10005073
    [\textbf{DUD}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10005654,
      before packing={calign with current},
      before typesetting nodes={
        repeat=\thepinkbosses{TeX={\stepcounter{countbosses}},insert before=pink boss \thecountbosses},
      }
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10005155
        [,phantom, minimum height=1ex
        ]
        [\textbf{BOB}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003570
          [\textbf{BAB}\\VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM, pink boss, alias=80000000
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{GOG}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003862
          [\textbf{GAG}\\VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM, name=80000001, pink boss
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{BUB}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10005556
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10003454
        [,phantom
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003770
        [,phantom
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10004035
        [,phantom
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\thepinkbosses}
    \draw[<-, dashed, black!30] (pink boss \i) -- (pink \i);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: dynamic pink bosses]

## EDIT

Here is the result of a little more experimentation with dynamic trees. This includes provision for green bosses as well as pink ones. A kind of 'half-level' is created between the root node and its primary child. This houses an empty node which ends up with a phantom and the green bosses as siblings.

Most of the coding is moved to the style settings in this version, so less manual intervention is required in the tree itself. The only manual intervention now required in the tree itself is the following:

- the main child of the root must have the style `important node`;
- the pink bosses must have the style `pink boss`;
- the green bosses must have the style `green boss`.

In addition, all counters should be reset between trees if more than one tree is to be typeset.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{pinkbosses}
\setcounter{pinkbosses}{0}
\newcounter{countpinkbosses}
\setcounter{countpinkbosses}{0}
\newcounter{greenbosses}
\setcounter{greenbosses}{0}
\newcounter{countgreenbosses}
\setcounter{countgreenbosses}{0}
\tikzset{
  /forest,
    pink boss/.style={
      edge path={},
      fill=red!25,
      TeX={\stepcounter{pinkbosses}},
      alias=pink boss \thepinkbosses,
      for parent={
        child anchor=west,
        calign=child edge,
        alias=pink \thepinkbosses,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
    },
    green boss/.style={
      edge path={},
      fill=green!25,
      TeX={\stepcounter{greenbosses}},
      alias=green boss \thegreenbosses,
      for parent={
        alias=green \thegreenbosses,
      },
    },
    important/.style={
      parent anchor=center,
      child anchor=center,
    },
    important node/.style={
      alias=important node,
      before packing={calign with current},
      before typesetting nodes={
        repeat=\thepinkbosses{TeX={\stepcounter{countpinkbosses}}, insert before=pink boss \thecountpinkbosses},
      },
    },
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      draw=black,
      align=center,
      l sep=6ex,
      node options={font=\scriptsize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
      where n children=0{}{
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-4ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
      where level=0{
        l sep=0pt,
        append={
          [, important, append=important node,
            before packing={calign with current},
          ]
        },
        append={
          [, phantom, xshift=20ex,
          ]
        },
        before typesetting nodes={
          repeat=\thegreenbosses{TeX={\stepcounter{countgreenbosses}},append=green boss \thecountgreenbosses},
        }
      }{},
      where level=2{
        for descendants={
          where n children=0{
              child anchor=west,
              calign=child edge,
              edge path={
                  \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                  ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
              },
              for parent={
                parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge,
              },
            }{},
        },
      }{},
      base=b
  }
  [\textbf{DDDDDDDDDDDD}\\SSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTT\\MMMMMMMMMMM, name=10005073
    [\textbf{DUD}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10005654, important node
      [\textbf{DAD}\\VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM, name=80011942, green boss
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10005155
        [,phantom, minimum height=1ex
        ]
        [\textbf{BOB}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003570
          [\textbf{BAB}\\VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM, pink boss, alias=80000000
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{GOG}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003862
          [\textbf{GAG}\\VVVVVVV\\MMMMMMMMMMM, name=80000001, pink boss
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{BUB}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10005556
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something here, name=10003454
        [,phantom
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10003770
        [,phantom
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{thing 1 here}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, name=10004035
      [\textbf{POP}\\thing 2 here\\something  here, green boss
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\thepinkbosses}
    \draw[<-, dashed, black!30] (pink boss \i) -- (pink \i);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\thegreenbosses}
    \draw[<-, dashed, black!30] (green boss \i) -- (green \i);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: pink and green bosses]

## YET ANOTHER EDIT

This version uses a phantom root node. This means that the apparent root is in level 1 although the real root is, of course, in level 0. Thus, the apparent root can have a sibling because the real root is the actual root of the tree:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\standaloneenv{forest}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{pinkbosses}
\setcounter{pinkbosses}{0}
\newcounter{countpinkbosses}
\setcounter{countpinkbosses}{0}
\tikzset{
  /forest,
    pink boss/.style={
      edge path={},
      fill=red!25,
      TeX={\stepcounter{pinkbosses}},
      alias=pink boss \thepinkbosses,
      for parent={
        child anchor=west,
        calign=child edge,
        alias=pink \thepinkbosses,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
    },
    green boss/.style={
      edge path={},
      fill=green!25,
      alias=green boss,
      for parent={
        alias=green parent,
      },
    },
    important/.style={
      parent anchor=center,
      child anchor=center,
    },
    important node/.style={
      alias=important node,
      before packing={calign with current},
      before typesetting nodes={
        repeat=\thepinkbosses{TeX={\stepcounter{countpinkbosses}}, insert before=pink boss \thecountpinkbosses},
      },
    },
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      draw=black,
      align=center,
      l sep=6ex,
      node options={font=\scriptsize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
      where n children=0{}{
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-4ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
      },
      where level=1{
        before typesetting nodes={
          insert after=green boss,
        },
      }{},
      where level=3{
        for descendants={
          where n children=0{
              child anchor=west,
              calign=child edge,
              edge path={
                  \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                  ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
              },
              for parent={
                parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge,
              },
            }{},
        },
      }{},
      base=b
  }
  [,phantom
  [\textbf{LEVEL 1}
      [\textbf{Thing 1}, important node
        [\textbf{Green Thing}, green boss
        ]
        [\textbf{Thing 2}
          [,phantom, minimum height=1ex
          ]
          [\textbf{Thing 3}
            [\textbf{Pink Thing 1}, pink boss
            ]
          ]
          [\textbf{Thing 4}
            [\textbf{Pink Thing 2}, pink boss
            ]
          ]
          [\textbf{Thing 5}
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{Thing 6}
          [,phantom
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{Thing 7}
          [,phantom
          ]
        ]
        [\textbf{Thing 8}
          [,phantom
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\thepinkbosses}
    \draw[<-, dashed, black!30] (pink boss \i) -- (pink \i);
  \draw[<-, dashed, black!30] (green boss) -- (green parent);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree with phantom root]

Comment: @ajeh It would be somewhat less confusing if you put something meaningful in the nodes and named them accordingly. It is difficult to understand what is going on with these meaningless strings. (Obviously you don't need real data but just something meaningful.)

Comment: I want them above, because they are the 2nd bosses. Let's forget about the green one completely for now. Geometrically you put the pink ones where they shold be. All I need is to be able to generate that chart automatically from a database. That would mean that their location would have to be specified only in terms of level where they need to be - 2nd level - and the rest (horizontal posisioning) should be handled by Forest automatically no matter how many pink nodes would be there.

Comment: Your edit puts the top pink boss into the level 3 in my opinion, and the bottom pink boss into the level 4. I cannot do that, as the charts would grow dramatically (too many employees have a 2nd boss). Your original answer has put the pink bosses where they should be. We do not need to worry about the green boss at all, I edited it out of the question too.

Comment: @ajeh It isn't a matter of opinion. When you say 'level n' in this context, I assume you are using the term technically in the sense `forest` uses it. If not, you should at least say, 'Of course, I'm not using "level" in the way `forest` does. When I say "level n", I'm referring to what `forest` calls "level n-1"' or whatever. The root is at `level 0`. That's just how `forest` works.

Comment: @ajeh So actually you want the pink bosses in level 1 (in `forest`'s terms - it is too confusing to say one level and code another). But then how can they be vertically stacked? Plus, in this case, I am not sure why my original solution isn't OK. As I said before, I don't see how `forest` is supposed to know which nodes are pink just by level given that there are non-pink nodes here, too.

Comment: I never said they need to be vertically stacked! On the contrary, I am trying to avoid that. Your original reply put them where they need to be. Informing Forest that some nodes need to be where the pink ones are is the whole point of this question. Color is only to visualize the question, that should not be done by color. When the application generates the Forest source, it knows which nodes are "2nd bosses", this is why I am wondering if I can instruct Forest somehow put them where you put them in your original reply. (I did not know that Forest numbered levels from 0 as I never used them)

Comment: Let's forget staggering for simplicity sake. But I simply do not see in your code the part that puts the 2nd bosses into the level #1.

Comment: The pink nodes need to be the children of the nodes in level 3 (in real world they can be levels 3, 7, 19 etc). Therefore they would become the level 4 nodes (or 8, 20 etc). But I want them in the level 1 regardless of what level nodes they are children of.

Comment: @ajeh You might want to tidy up the comments a bit. Also, see my edit. (Not really an edit. A different answer.) I reduced the text in the nodes as I have a small screen and I couldn't see what I was doing. Also, all those repeated letters were just confusing and hard to keep track of. (For me. Maybe you are fine with distinguishing 14 `d`s from 15 visually.) Note that the pink bosses are not now children of their original parents. As far as `forest` is concerned, they ***are*** in level 1 i.e. siblings of DUD.

Comment: This is great! I am still going through the code leanrning what it is doing, but here's one thing I noticed: there can be only 1 green boss (from DUD at line 102). When I remove the 2nd green boss at line 127, the edge to the node 10004035 becomes a straight line. Why?

Comment: @ajeh You just need to replace the `phantom` node in that case. I replaced it with a green boss just to show that the code worked as expected. If you *just* remove the green boss, the code treats `10004035` as it does other terminal nodes. (You will see the same thing if you remove the `phantom` children of `10004035`'s siblings.)

Comment: And which part of the code puts the green boss in between of DDDDD and DUD? I will have to put it in the level 0 instead.

Comment: @ajeh It is in the code for `level 0`. In `before typesetting nodes`, the `append` instruction places the node as a new child of the root node. You cannot make it a sibling of the root node because the root node cannot have siblings but only children. You could try setting the anchors of `level 1` children to `south`, or setting a negative `l sep` to fake it. Or you could use a `phantom` node as the root of the tree i.e. make `level n` actually `level n+1`.

Comment: @ajeh Did that help?

Comment: I'll know in a few weeks, still trying to see how that can be automated.

Comment: @ajeh So..... ?